# Problem with Firebase filters, how can i solve?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first post here. I'm learning JS and how to use Firebase. I'm making a do to list with some filters, but every time I change the filters, a new request is being made. So when I submit the file, it shows the added task several times on the screen

https://prnt.sc/F8cePcmzzMvj

In this example, I changed the filters 4 times, so when I add the task, it is rendered 4 times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aijda.png)

The same thing was happening with login and logout, but then I put a removeEventListener and it is working perfectly, but I have no idea how to do it with the filters.

```js
const updateOrderList = user => {
    let inputName = 'taskValue';
    let orderValue = orderBy(inputName);
    let whereValue = '';

    orderAscDesc.forEach(radio => {
        if (!radio.checked) return;

        if (radio.value === 'order__asc') {
            orderValue = orderBy(inputName);
            clearLis();
        } else if (radio.value === 'order__desc') {
            orderValue = orderBy(inputName, 'desc');
            clearLis();
        }
    });

    orderChecked.forEach(radio => {
        if (!radio.checked) return;

        if (radio.value === 'Completas') {
            whereValue = where("checked", "==", true);
            clearLis();
        } else if (radio.value === 'Incompletas') {
            whereValue = where("checked", "==", false);
            clearLis();
        }
    });

    orderAlphaDate.forEach(radio => {
        if (!radio.checked) return;

        if (radio.value === 'data') {
            inputName = 'date';
            clearLis();
        } else if (radio.value === 'alpha') {
            inputName = 'taskValue';
            clearLis();
        }
    });

    const onlyUser = where('userID', '==', user.uid);
    const queryPhrases = query(
        collectionTask, 
        whereValue, 
        onlyUser,
        orderValue
    );

    clearLis();
    onSnapshot(queryPhrases, renderTasks);
};
```

I just want the filter to work without having to refresh the page every time